# Fancytree not expand node after reload

Tags: jquery, reload, expand, treenode, fancytree

I'm working with fancytree.

How can open a node (lazy) after it was reload in javascript?

Code:

```
node.load(forceReload = true);
node.setExpanded();
```

When execute node.setExpanded() I get "Assertion failed" error. I think that the problem is executing the setExpanded() instruction before that node.load() is executing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
node.load(true).done(function(){
  node.setExpanded();
});
```

See also http://www.wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/FancytreeNode.html

Comment: for setExpanded, I get error: Fancytree assertion failed: only init supported. Note that I am using parentNode.resetLazy(); before node.load